# Is there a way to save all the Azure DevOps work item with links, attachments in excel?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We are trying to save all the Azure DevOps project data. In that process, I would like to know whether we can download all the work item data (i.e; along with links, child items, attachments, etc.)in excel?

Comment: How do you propose to store attachments in excel?

Comment: We can't download all the data directly in excel, at least the attachments can't be downloaded via export to csv option. Rest api may be one option, or download them manually via web portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We are trying to save all the Azure DevOps project data. In that
> process, I would like to know whether we can download all the work
> item data (i.e; along with links, child items, attachments, etc.)in
> excel?

We can't download **all** the work item data in excel. The easily way to export work item data is `Export to CSV` option, check [Export list as CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#export-list-as-csv). You can specify the the data types you need in the csv file via `Column Options`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

It supports Work Item Types, States,Tag, Priority, Parent and many other types. However it doesn't support data like attachments. The attachments are always binary files, you need to download them via web portal or [Rest API](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/380413/cannot-get-list-of-work-item-attachments-using-res.html).

Comment: Much appreciated for your response. Thanks. Will use the Rest API to get the attachments, links etc.

Comment: @Nanab4u Glad to know it makes some help. Feel free to contact me if you meet any issue when calling the api~ If my answer resolves your issue, you could [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your Backlog with all your items unrolled, then go to column options, add a Parent column, click on OK, then when you go back you can see all your items with their parent link. click on the first Item, then click on Tab + down arrow, until you select all items. click on Ctrl + C, then paste it on excel, it should work, if not try with word.

Comment: Thanks. It works for getting the supported data types.

Answer (score 0):

If 'Export to CSV/ Send as mail' suits the requirement go with it. If not install azure devops office integration and connect to excel.
[Export work-items to Excel](https://medium.com/@aabeing/export-work-items-from-azure-devops-board-to-microsoft-excel-4e827492e026)